# How to make vscode's intellisense ignore some errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a c++ project that depends on ImageMagick. I include it in my files as `#include <Magick++.h>`. The app compiles and runs without errors in CLion IDE. When I opened the project in Vscode, the project still runs ofcourse, but intellisense gives error message in the file where I have `#include <Magick++.h>`:

```
cannot open source file "MagickCore/version.h" (dependency of "Magick++.h")C/C++(1696)
```

I searched for the mentioned header file and I didn't find it, so vscode is right to complain about it. (note: I added the ImageMagick library by cloning the source code and pasting it in my project in a directory called deps)

But since the project runs normally, I just want to supress this error. I tried the `disable error squiggles` option (when I hover the mouse over the error) but this disables all errors from intellisense. So how can I supress the desired error only?

Note: I don't want to manipulate the library source files, so I prefer a solution within the settings of vscode

Comment: You need to configure the intellisense properly, there's no other way. Either the file exists somewhere, and you need to add an include directory, or there's some macro that needs to be defined, or something else. You can also try Clangd instead of the stock intellisense (it should be more intuitive to configure, and just better in general).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, Clangd worked perfectly, and the error is gone. I will use it from now on instead. Please post this as an aswer as it solves the problem

Comment: Which compiler is configured for you VSC?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews its clang++, i already tried alot of the available ones but none of them changed anything. I am on linux also. And as I said above,the header file is actually not present so.vscode is right to complain